# How to fix menu item highlight color when press in Android

Tags: android, menu, background, menuitem, highlight

Anyone know how to disable the highlight background in menu item when I press menu item.

Below is the screen.

[image: Image of Menu Hightlight background when press]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Application gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```